# Specify elastic result size in query key instead of the size key

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I know that I can limit the number of the result Elastic returns with the key "size," but I don't have access to use this key in a custom Elastic dashboard and I only have access to set the "query" key, I want to limit the number of results of my query.

Comment: You can also set the `size` as a query string parameter in the URL: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-search-api-query-params

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have access to the "query" in the body and nothing else.

Comment: You're out of luck then, sorry. I'm curious about the rationale behind this design, though.